# Variable in SQL while loop doesn't increase

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, sapb1

With code below, I'm only getting a `4` as result. If I change my `set @ counter = 4` to `set @counter=5`, I get only `5` in the end.  I'm using SAP Business One query generator. How is this not working? If I put `select @counter` after `END` I actually get a `11`... So the loop actually runs.

```
DECLARE @Counter int
SET @Counter = 4
WHILE @Counter <= 10
BEGIN
select @counter
SET @Counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? This must have something to do with whatever this SAP thing is. I noticed that you have Counter and counter. In my database that would fail because we have a case sensitive collation. And no idea what a cte has to do with this?

Comment: It is working fine on SQL Server 2016 SP1.

Comment: take out the `select @counter` and put it after `END`. Check if you're getting 11 or not. Its part of debugging.

Comment: This is interesting, because if I put select @counter at the end I actually get a 11....so the loop actually runs, but breaks when it runs select?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right to me... The problem might be in the manner you wrote the variable names. Try using same capitalization when its a single variable: @counter and @Counter.

Also try to use select instead of set. They do pretty much the same thing, but might work better in your case.

```
SELECT @Counter = @Counter + 1
```

Edit after reading comments:
If your select outside the loop shows 11, try to print inside the loop instead of selecting just to check if it shows 4 too.

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 4
WHILE @counter<= 10
BEGIN
    PRINT @counter
    SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: the thing with sap is that I cant use print, I can only use select. It runs but it doesnt print anything even if I just type Print 1

Answer (score 0):

SAP Business One query manager just shows the result of the first select statement. In your case, you could store all the data in a temp table and select that table when you get out of the loop.

```
declare @temp table (mynum int)
DECLARE @Counter int
SET @Counter = 4
WHILE @Counter <= 10
BEGIN
   insert into @temp select @counter
   SET @Counter = @counter + 1
END

select * from @temp
```